# pyquibase error: subprocess.CalledProcessError

Tags: python, sqlite

I use python and I want to create a database source controller like [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org). 
I find the python version of liquibase call [pyquibase](https://github.com/rampart81/pyquibase#pyquibase)
 but get `subprocess.CalledProcessError`

this is my simple code:

```
from pyquibase.pyquibase import Pyquibase

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyquibase = Pyquibase.sqlite('test.sqlite', 'db-changelog-1.xml')
    pyquibase.update()
```

and I got these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ali/dev/project/python/DatabaseSourceContoller/DatabaseSourceContoller/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    pyquibase.update()
  File "/home/ali/dev/project/python/DatabaseSourceContoller/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyquibase/pyquibase.py", line 69, in update
    output = self.liquibase.execute(self.change_log_file, "update")
  File "/home/ali/dev/project/python/DatabaseSourceContoller/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyquibase/liquibase_executor.py", line 103, in execute
    shell  = True
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 316, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 398, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'java -jar /home/ali/dev/project/python/DatabaseSourceContoller/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyquibase/liquibase/liquibase.jar     --driver=org.sqlite.JDBC     --classpath=/home/ali/dev/project/python/DatabaseSourceContoller/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyquibase/db-connectors/sqlite-jdbc-3.18.0.jar     --changeLogFile=db-changelog-1.xml     --url="jdbc:sqlite:test.sqlite" update' returned non-zero exit status 255
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pyquibase](https://github.com/rampart81/pyquibase#pyquibase) forks a child process to execute the liquibase changelog update. And the `subprocess.CalledProcessError` means that the liquibase changelog update has failed.

Now, in order to find out why it failed, you can run the liquibase command manually to see the actual error messages:

`java -jar /home/ali/dev/project/python/DatabaseSourceContoller/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyquibase/liquibase/liquibase.jar     --driver=org.sqlite.JDBC     --classpath=/home/ali/dev/project/python/DatabaseSourceContoller/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyquibase/db-connectors/sqlite-jdbc-3.18.0.jar     --changeLogFile=db-changelog-1.xml     --url="jdbc:sqlite:test.sqlite" update`

[pyquibase](https://github.com/rampart81/pyquibase#pyquibase) doesn't print the actual error messages for you yet. The next version upgrade should have that feature.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, it worked through the command directly but not through pyquibase.update() =(